# C++: error: expected primary-expression

Tags: c++, function

```
void add(int register, int& acc)
{
    acc += register;
}
```

main.cpp:124: error: expected primary-expression before ‘register’

wth is wrong right there?

Answer (score 8):

"[register](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/register)" is a keyword in C++ (a hangover from C days, mostly)

Answer (score 4):

`register` is a C++ keyword, rename this to something else. It's used to qualify variables as a hint to the compiler to optimize the variable's storage directly to a CPU register rather than RAM - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/482s4fy9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).